# check for audio voice driver installed in c#

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

i use a sound player in my winform application.
Is there a way to check for sound cards driver (is installed/or not installed)on OS? 
i want to chek it programatelly in c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got it

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("winmm.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern uint waveOutGetNumDevs();

private void frmSound_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e){
if(waveOutGetNumDevs() != 0)
{
  lblSound.Text = "The Sound device is detected for this system";
}
else
{
    lblSound.ForeColor = Color.Red; 
    lblSound.Text = "The Sound device is Not Found for this system";
}
}
```